# mysql update table column from another table with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am trying to work out how to perform an SQL UPDATE table column from Table A into Table B. The problem I have is trying to concat multiple values from Table A Column X into Table B Column Y

TableA Structure
id | Interest
1  | Bowling
2  | Swimming
1  | Basketball

TableB Structure
id | Interest_new
1  | null
2  | null

I want Table B to have following data

TableB
id | Interest_new
1  | Bowling,Basketball
2  | Swimming

This is my attempt with SQL query but it doesn't concat , just updated table B with first match

```
    UPDATE TableB 
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.id= TableA.id
SET TableB.id=CONCAT(TableA.id, ',')
where TableA.id= TableB.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably intend to use `GROUP_CONCAT` here, as you want an aggregated CSV output:

```sql
UPDATE TableB b
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(Interest ORDER BY id) Interests
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY id
) a
    ON a.id = b.id
SET
    Interest_new = a.Interests;
```

However, I actually advocate *not* even doing this, as storing CSV in your SQL tables is a generally bad idea.  Consider just making a view of this data instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW newInterests AS
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(Interest ORDER BY id) Interests
FROM TableA
GROUP BY id;
```